# chart.js und Vue.js How to make a line charts scrollable horizontally?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, scroll, quasar

```
chart.js with Vue.js Does anyone know how to create scrollable charts with 
vue.js? I have a very long 
line chart with over a year on the x axis. If you change the view of 
the browser to the mobile screen, labels on the x-axis interpenetrate, making 
it impossible to read different categories.
```

I am looking for ways to solve this by making the graph scroll horizontally. Is that possible?